# Sequence as key of YAML mapping in python

Tags: python, yaml, sequence

By reading a YAML file, I'd like to get the following python dictionary:

```
mydict = {('x','x'): 4}
```

or:

```
mydict = {['x','x']: 4}
```

Basically, I want a tuple or list as a key in a dictionary. This is the YAML I've tried:

```
mydict:
   !!python/tuple [e,e]: 4 # valid, but python-specific
   !!python/list [b,b]: 4 # error: "found unhashable key"
   [c,c]: 4 # error: "found unhashable key"
   !!seq [d,d]: 4 # error: "found unhashable key"
```

I'm using PyYAML, so either the YAML code has to be YAML1.1 syntax, or you could recommend me a better way to store this kind of data in a text file. I've thought of `json.load`, but JSON does not accept arrays as mapping keys.

Thanks =)

Comment: FYI: Dictionary keys must be hashable in Python, so lists (which can change and therefore don't have a consistent hash code) are out. dicts and sets are out, too, though frozensets are not. Tuples are immutable, though, so they will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to use a list as a hash key in Python. It's mutable. You have to use a tuple.

Comment: Alright, then why is `!!seq [d,d]: 4` not working? Using the `?  :` syntax for complex mappings does not help.

Answer (score 1):

I also looked into this by using the debugger under Eclipse/PyDev, and studying the structure of the YAML objects returned. I found that I could get around the specific error about the unhashable key without using python-specific types by reforming the YAML object to use a python tuple rather than a list, but this is only an illusion of being a solution. A key to a dictionary in  PyYAML has to be a MappingNode. Even though this can be implemented as a Python tuple of values, internally it is still treated as a set (i.e. subject to uniqifying and re-ordering). This means that different tuples (such as (a,a,b), (a,b,a), (b,a) etc.) may end up being treated as the same key, which is not what you want.

For info, this is what I did. I defined a Python class to construct a new MappingNode using a tuple rather than a list when it encountered a YAML sequence something like this:

```
class Key(yaml.YAMLObject):

  yaml_tag = "tag:example.com:2013:Key"
  @classmethod
  def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
    if isinstance(node, yaml.SequenceNode):
      new_values = []
      for v in node.value:
        new_values.append( (v, yaml.ScalarNode(tag=u'tag:yaml.org,2002:null'), value=u'')) )
      node = yaml.MappingNode(tag=node.tag, value=tuple(new_values))
    return loader.construct_yaml_object(node,cls)
```

I then used this class for keys for sequence keys something like this in my YAML data:

```
!<tag:example.com:2013:Key> [a, b]: 3
```

or:

```
%TAG !mytags! tag:example.com:2013:
---
......
  !mytags!Key [a, b]: 3
```

However, this does not preserve the sequence in the way that you would expect, as I explained. Personally I would not use this code/approach in any real applications.

Using a set rather than a sequence seems safer to me, although it isn't quite what you asked about. This uses the [set type](http://yaml.org/type/set.html) from [Language-Independent Types for YAML Version 1.1](http://yaml.org/type/). I used the analogous approach to the sequence type above, but since PyYAML uses a Python list for the key of a MappingType, I only needed to change it to a tuple like this:

```
class Key(yaml.YAMLObject):

  yaml_tag = "tag:example.com:2013:Key"
  @classmethod
  def from_yaml(cls, loader, node):
    if isinstance(node, yaml.MappingNode):
      node.value = tuple(node.value)
    return loader.construct_yaml_object(node, cls)
```

and use sets as keys in the YAML data something like this:

```
!mytags!Key {a, b}: 3
```

All this looks like a limitation with PyYAML to me: theoretically I don't think that there is anything about YAML itself that disallows a sequence being used as a key like you want.

Comment: Thanks for the very complete feedback! Sadly, using sets as keys would not work for me. FYI, I've moved on past YAML, and started using a CSV file instead; my YAML code (and the lists/tuples of keys and/or values) started getting long.